# jQuery menu not switching between pages

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having problems with some jQuery menu that I'm writing, it seems to not be allowing me to switch between the "div pages" I have set up. I've uploaded what I've done here http://jsfiddle.net/UxNMT/ and would very much appreciate any insight into what I'm doing wrong.

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#menu").menu();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#1').show();

    $("#1").click(function () {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#1').show();
    });

    $("#2").click(function () {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#2').show();
    });

    $("#3").click(function () {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#3').show();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:150px; background-color: #EFEFEF; float:left;">
    <ul id="menu" style="border: 0px; background:none">
        <li><a id="1" style="cursor: pointer">1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="2" style="cursor: pointer">2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="3" style="cursor: pointer">3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="float:right; width: 595px; text-align:left; font-family: Verdana; 
padding: 10px; ">
    <div id="1" style="display: none" class="content">1</div>
    <div id="2" style="display: none" class="content">2</div>
    <div id="3" style="display: none" class="content">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **IDs must be unique.** You have the same id for the links and the content, so it doesn't work. See http://jsfiddle.net/UxNMT/2/

Comment: Although HTML5 specification says that you can use any character for naming it is better (due to backward compatible issues) to follow the rules of HTML4: "The ID elements must start with a letter i.e. upper case A to Z or lower case a to z; a number is not allowed."